# Infinite series of a function involving an enumeration of rationals on $0,1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{ q_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $(0,1)$ and define

$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad \text{if} \; x \in (0, q_n) \\
2^{-n} \quad \: \text{if} \; x \in [q_n, 1)\end{cases}$

and

$\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \; , \quad x \in (0,1)$

The first part of the question asks to show $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1 \quad \forall x \in (0,1)$ and that $f$ is strictly increasing which I could do.

Next I am asked to show if $x_0 \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ then

$\exists \epsilon > 0 : f(x) < f(x_0) - \epsilon \quad \forall x \in (0,x_0)$

I tried to argue by contradiction but can't get to anything useful. Can anyone provide a bit of direction here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some $m$ with $x_0=q_m$. For all $x\in(0,x_0)$, $f_m(x)=0$, while $f_m(x_0)=2^{-m} $. As all the $f_n$ are increasing, 
$$
f(x_0)-f(x)=2^{-m}+\sum_{n\ne m}f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)\geq2^{-m}.
$$
Now you can take $\epsilon=2^{-m-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that

$$\forall  x_0 \in (0,1).\ \forall x \in (0,x_0).\ \exists \varepsilon > 0.\ f(x_0) - f(x) > \varepsilon.$$

Let $x_0$ be an arbitrary number in $(0,1)$. Observe, that $x \in (0,x_0)$ implies $x < x_0$, in other words, $(x,x_0)$ is a valid, non-empty interval.

As $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we know that $(x,x_0)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is non-empty, hence, fix any $p \in (x,x_0)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Now, $p \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ so there exists $n$ such that $p = q_n$.

Therefore, $f_n(x) = 0$ and $f_n(x_0) = 2^{-n}$, so for $\varepsilon = 2^{-n-1}$ we have that $$f(x_0)-f(x) \geq f_n(x_0) - f_n(x) > \varepsilon.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$